# text-shadow working only one time

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I try to applied two shadows on stars of font awesome set like this : http://jsfiddle.net/myYUh/117/

There is problem with this part :

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #190C80;
text-shadow: -2px -2px 2px #190C80;
```

the shadow is only of top left, so only one shadow is displayed, even if i try this in one line, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

To add multiple shadows combine them and separate with `,`

```
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #190C80, -2px -2px 2px #190C80;
```

This works for all shadows in CSS.

1. text-shadow
2. box-shadow

Little tutorial:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding the first shadow with the second one.

If you want multiple shadows, set them using a comma:

```css
text-shadow: 2px  2px 2px #190C80,
            -2px -2px 2px #190C80;
```

```css
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.rating span.star {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 2px  2px 2px #190C80,
              -2px -2px 2px #190C80;
}
.rating span.star:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating span.star:before {
  content: "\f005";
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #777777;
}
.rating span.star:hover:before,
.rating span.star:hover ~ span.star:before {
  content: "\f005";
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="evaluation_technique">
  <span class="rating">
    <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  </span>
</p>
```

This is explained in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow):

> **`text-shadow`**
>
> This property accepts a comma-separated list of shadow effects to be
>   applied to the text of the element.